# Verify href with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, href, verify

In my online shop I have some links in product pages which go to a template which the user can download.  Unfortunately, as I have many of these links, some are broken, because the file is missing.

Is there some function, preferably in javascript, that allows me to check if the link is correct?  If it's ok, only "continue linking" to allow the download, and if it's broken, show an alert which says something like "Uh, file is missing, please report this clicking here"

Comment: I think it should be the server that verifies if the download is valid or not - after all, it already knows as soon as the request comes in for the download.

Comment: What's your server-side look like?

Comment: You could perform a get to the href and check if it fails with a 404. If you're using jQuery, you could do something like `$.get('url', function() { // same logic as before }).fail(function() { //not found, tell user });`

Comment: My shop is developed in Prestashop

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaScript won't have access to the server's file system, I believe you would need some server-side code.  An easy way of accomplishing this is to write a web service that accepts a filename(string).  Have it return a boolean.  Something like this:

```
        [WebMethod]
        public bool CheckFile(string FileName)
        {
            return File.Exists(FileName);
        }
```

Then, when someone clicks the link, you can call your WebService and write a CallBackFunction which evaluates the returned value.  If it's true, you execute the logic you (presumably) already have.  If it's false, you can pop a modal informing them that the file no longer exists on the server.

Comment: And to clarify: This doesn't HAVE to be a web service - you could declare a public function in the code-behind.  But without knowing exactly what platform you're using, this came to mind, first.

Comment: I'm using Prestashop, and, to be honest, and have no idea what are you talking about, can you tell me something about I can read to understand it better?

Comment: Sure.  A web service is essentially a function that has an http endpoint.  It can be called from client-side script and can return pretty much anything.  Since the client-side script won't be able to 'check and see' if a file exists on a remote server - and you don't want to post your entire page back to check, a web service is your best bet.  Read up on 'Web Services' and 'AJAX'.  That should teach you how to write the web service, deploy it to a server, and consume it with client-side script.  Happy hunting - it might seem like a lot at first, but it's not that complicated once you're going.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I need to read about it because I have no idea. But... considering my store is based on Prestashop. Exists something concrete that I can look for?

Comment: I don't know anything about Prestashop, so I can't answer that.  But Web Services and AJAX are staples of web development.  If you are working on any kind of complex web-site, you'll almost certainly need both, so it will be good for you to start learning, now.  Lots of material out there.